# Underlying reasoning behind lead and lag nomenclature of compensation

Tags: control-system, phase, bode-plot, compensation

If \$0<z, \;p\$, the Laplace transform transfer function \$\frac{s+z}{s+p}\$ constitute two distinct types of compensators.

If we look at [this schematic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7C0p.jpg), \$0<z<p\$ *(lead compensation) implies that for \$s=\omega j\$ with \$0<\omega\$, \$s+z\$ clearly lies to the left of \$s+p\$ so that \$0<\arg(\frac{s+z}{s+p})=\tan^{−1}(\frac{p−z}{\omega^2+pz})<\frac{\pi}{2}\$.*

Similarly, \$0<z<p\$ *(lag compensation) implies that for \$s=\omega j\$ with \$0<\omega\$, \$s+z\$ is to the right of \$s+p\$ so that \$-\frac{\pi}{2}<\arg(\frac{s+z}{s+p})=\tan^{−1}(\frac{p−z}{\omega^2+pz})<0\$.*

> Is the following understanding about the phase with regards to the *lead* and *lag* compensation accurate? *The relative location of the complex numbers \$s+z\$ and \$s+p\$ is the underlying reason that the lead compensation adds (and a lag subtracts) phase to the transfer function it multiplies.*

Comment: Where did the quoted text question come from? Is it homework?

Comment: @Andyaka this is not a homework-and-exercises question.

Comment: Lead compensator provide phase lead at all the frequencies of input signal and by setting p and z appropriately you can get max phase lead at desired frequency , but you yourself answer the question by showing how phase shift takes place in lead or lag compensator

Comment: @user215805 thanks for the comment. The intention of the question is to ascertain the geometric explanation of the phase manipulation using lead or lag compensation.